# Filtering xml file to remove lines with certain text in them?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

For example, suppose I have:

```
<div class="info"><p><b>Orange</b>, <b>One</b>, ...
<div class="info"><p><b>Blue</b>, <b>Two</b>, ...
<div class="info"><p><b>Red</b>, <b>Three</b>, ...
<div class="info"><p><b>Yellow</b>, <b>Four</b>, ...
```

And I'd like to remove all lines that have words from a list so I'll only use xpath on the lines that fit my criteria. For example, I could use the list as `['Orange', 'Red']` to mark the unwanted lines, so in the above example I'd only want to use lines 2 and 4 for further processing.

How can I do this?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, but short and simple one-liner XPath expression solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//div
  [not(p/b[contains('|Orange|Red|', 
                    concat('|', ., '|')
                   )
          ]
       )
  ]
```

This selects any `div` elements in the XML document, such that it has no `p` child whose `b` child's string valu is one of the strings in the pipe-separated list of strings to use as filters.

This approach allows extensibility by just adding new filter values to the pipe-separated list, without changing anything else in the XPath expression.

**Note**: When the structure of the XML document is statically known, always avoid using the `//` XPath pseudo-operator, because it leads to significant inefficiency (slowdown).

Answer (score 0):

```
import lxml.html as lh

# http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html
# http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/index.html
content='''\
<table>
<div class="info"><p><b>Orange</b>, <b>One</b></p></div>
<div class="info"><p><b>Blue</b>, <b>Two</b></p></div>
<div class="info"><p><b>Red</b>, <b>Three</b></p></div>
<div class="info"><p><b>Yellow</b>, <b>Four</b></p></div>
</table>
'''
NS = 'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'
tree = lh.fromstring(content)
exclude=['Orange','Red']
for elt in tree.xpath(
    "//div[not(re:test(p/b[1]/text(), '{0}'))]".format('|'.join(exclude)),
    namespaces={'re': NS}):
    print(lh.tostring(elt))
    print('-'*80)
```

yields

```
<div class="info"><p><b>Blue</b>, <b>Two</b></p></div>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="info"><p><b>Yellow</b>, <b>Four</b></p></div>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```